# XSL parent node data in child node

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, xsd

Source XML:

```
<COVER_DETAIL>
    <COVERDETAILS>
        <COVERNAME>AAA</COVERNAME>
        <EFFECTIVEDATE>2010-04-30</EFFECTIVEDATE>
        <EXPIRYDATE>2022-03-31</EXPIRYDATE>
        <COVERAMOUNT/>
        <COVERPERCENT/>
        <COVERCODE>60</COVERCODE>
    </COVERDETAILS>
    <COVERDETAILS>
        <COVERNAME>BBB</COVERNAME>
        <EFFECTIVEDATE>2010-04-30</EFFECTIVEDATE>
        <EXPIRYDATE>2022-03-31</EXPIRYDATE>
        <COVERAMOUNT/>
        <COVERPERCENT/>
        <COVERCODE>60</COVERCODE>
    </COVERDETAILS>
    <COVERDETAILS>
        <COVERNAME>CCC</COVERNAME>
        <EFFECTIVEDATE>2022-04-01</EFFECTIVEDATE>
        <EXPIRYDATE>2032-03-31</EXPIRYDATE>
        <COVERAMOUNT/>
        <COVERPERCENT>100</COVERPERCENT>
        <COVERCODE>62</COVERCODE>
    </COVERDETAILS>
    <COVERDETAILS>
        <COVERNAME>DDD</COVERNAME>
        <EFFECTIVEDATE>2022-04-01</EFFECTIVEDATE>
        <EXPIRYDATE>2032-03-31</EXPIRYDATE>
        <COVERAMOUNT/>
        <COVERPERCENT/>
        <COVERCODE>85</COVERCODE>
    </COVERDETAILS>
</COVER_DETAIL>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template name="COVERDETAILS">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
                <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="COVERNAME"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block> --- Here i want to display percentage </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I apply the `coverpercent` value of `covercode` `62` to as `coverpercent` value of all other covers in for each template. I want to apply the `coverpecent` of cover with `covercode` `62` to each and every other cover.

Comment: That's not quite clear. Do you want to hard-code the value "62" in the stylesheet?

Comment: hi michael, yes i wanna hardcode 62 in stylesheet

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by defining a variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="perc" select="/COVER_DETAIL/COVERDETAILS[COVERCODE='62']/COVERPERCENT" />
```

Then use this variable inside your template, where you want to display the percentage as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$perc"/>
```